# PYTHON: Use of this ',' in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Just out of curiosity, what does this ',' do in python?
for e.g.

```
print "5 + 5 = ", 5 + 5
```

exactly what work does it perform?

Comment: `,` is an implicit operator for constructing tuples. `"5 + 5 = ", 5 + 5` is equivalent to `("5 + 5 = ", 5 + 5)`.

Comment: @DYZ I really wanted to say that, but for `print` in 2.7, `a= 1, 2` then `print a` gives `(1, 2)`, yet a print statement separated by a comma does not print as a tuple.

Comment: @roganjosh Right, comma has several uses. In `print` in 2.7, it works more like a parameter separator.

Comment: Yes, here the comma is part of the [`print` statement syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement). Also see the [Python 2 tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming).

Comment: Unless you're simply reading python 2 code, Suggestion: Learn Python 3 instead

Comment: @cricket_007 I am learning Python from LPTHW. Zed says that I should learn Python 2.7 because Python 3 is for future.

Comment: @Mate take a bit of what you need from it and then move on to Google/here. It wasn't long ago that I was following it and it leaves a lot of questions/things unanswered. I'm on 2.7 because work needs it, you should probably jump to P3 if you can. If you search around for him online, he's a volatile and opinionated person in the extreme, don't take what he says too literally :)

Comment: For balance: https://eev.ee/blog/2016/11/23/a-rebuttal-for-python-3/

Comment: The future is closer than you think. https://pythonclock.org/